# Java Deprecation annotation

Tags: java, eclipse

I made two classes as instructed to me by people here and now calling the deprecated function from one class to the other(See my previous [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157628/java-standard-annotations)).

I have even put the @SuppressWarnings line over the function call but still it won't work.I don't understand why. I need to stop the deprecation warning from showing by using the @SuppressWarnings annotation. Can anyone tell me where to place it?

Deprecated class

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

@interface number {
    String arm();
}

public class armstrong {
    @Deprecated
    @number(arm = "Armstrong number")
    public static void armStrong(int n) {
        int temp, x, sum = 0;
        temp = n;
        while(temp!=0) {
            x = temp % 10;
            sum = sum + x * x * x;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        if(sum == n) {
            System.out.println("It is an armstrong number");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("It is not an armstrong number");
        }
    }
}
```

Class using the deprecated one

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Ch10LU2Ex4 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 100 and 999:");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            armstrong obj = new armstrong();
            obj.armStrong(x);
            Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("armStrong", Integer.TYPE);
            Annotation[] annos = method.getAnnotations();
            for(int i = 0; i<annos.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(annos[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the question? And BTW, a deprecation is just a warning at compile time, it won't stop your code from running.

Comment: "it won't work." how? What is the goal?

Comment: I know it won't cause any problem. I am trying to learn the working of annotations. So I need to make the SuppressWarnings annotation work.

Comment: put it just before `public static void main`.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon It didn't work :(

Comment: Are you making sure you clean and rebuild the whole thing?

Comment: What is the error message you get from the compiler. It's working fine here (except you should definitely use `armstrong.armStrong()` instead of `obj.armStrong()` since `armStrong()` is a static method, and you should respect Java namin conventions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` is attached to the default Constructor.

### Warnings do not change the execution

Warnings are only for Compile-Time

You must point the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` to the method `main` itself of to the Class `Ch10LU2Ex4`!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Ch10LU2Ex4 {  
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 100 and 999:");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            armstrong obj = new armstrong();
            obj.armStrong(x);
            Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("armStrong", Integer.TYPE);
            Annotation[] annos = method.getAnnotations();
            for(int i = 0; i<annos.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(annos[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A annotation is always attached to the next identifier on the right/bottom.

Comment: Because I ran it...this is the output:

Enter a number between 100 and 999:
153
It is an armstrong number
@java.lang.Deprecated()
@number(arm=Armstrong number)

Comment: Ok, your question is wrong then! "Warnings" are used by the compiler only. Not while running the code!

Comment: Err: of course it does that, since you're printing all the annotations on the armStrong() method. SuppressWarnings will not *delete* the annotation on a method. It will only make *the compiler* not emit a deprecation warning for *the usage* of the deprecated method in `main()`.

Comment: oh...so then u r saying that the "@java.lang.Deprecated()" will always come but the supresswarnings annotation would just prevent the deprecation warning from coming?

Comment: @JBNizet Indeed are the Annotations used, the Annotations are used while Running. But: The Warnings are used by the compiler only. ;D, can we flatten it up to this JB?

Comment: @Robin thats it. After all compiler-warnings are only for the compiler, not the interpreter.

Comment: Ohhhh...thank you so much...I have been sitting on this since the past 2 hours and now I am finding out that nothing was wrong...crap!!! thanks a lot :D

Comment: @PeterRader: my comment was for Robin, not for you. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

What if you move it in front of `main` method?

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args)
```